Closed path integral of $Log(z+2)$ along $|z|=1$
Let $\alpha$ be the boundary of the circle $|z|=1$ with positive orientation. Is the following integral is well defined?. If it is well defined, what is its value?
$$ \int_{\alpha}Log(z+2)dz $$
$Log$ is the principal branch of the logarithm,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ccl}
Log: & V_0 \to&  U_0\\
&z \mapsto &Log(z)=log|z|+iArg(z)
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
where $V_0=\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,+\infty)$ and $U_0=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: 0<Im(z)<2\pi\}$.
I gather the domain of $Log(z+2)$ would be $D=\mathbb{C}\setminus[-2,+\infty)$, this implies that there are two points of the circle $\alpha$ which are not in the domain of $Log(z+2)$, namely -1 and 1, then the path integral would not be well defined. Is this correct?
I wrote this in a test but the teacher marked it as incorrect, is there any way around the domain problem? I was thinking that maybe I should divide the path $\alpha$ in two segments $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$, one above the real axis and one below, then
$$ \int_{\alpha}Log(z+2)dz =\int_{\alpha_1}Log(z+2)dz +\int_{\alpha_2}Log(z+2)dz $$
and then consider $\int_{\alpha_1}Log(z+2)dz $ as some sort of improper integral since the end-points of $\alpha_1$ are again not in the domain of $Log(z+2)$, but I don't know if this makes any sense.
Thanks in advance for any comment.

If you are using the principal branch for $\log$ then the above function is analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty, -2]$ and since the unit circle lies entirely in this set the integral is zero.

Thanks @copper.hat, I get it now :)

To sum up, the branch of the logarithm that I took wasn't adequate, in my class the teacher defined the principal branch on $\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,+\infty)$ but apparently that is not the standard definition of $Log$ but $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$ where everything works.
